# Domain Definition in Scaled Function

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Suppose the function $f(x)$ is defined on the domain $\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$, so that the graph of $y=f(x)$ consists of just three points. Suppose those three points form a triangle of area $32$.

The graph of $y = 2f(2x)$ also consists of just three points. What is the area of the triangle formed by those three points?

If I look at the properties of functions using shifting / scaling, etc, then I can arrive at an answer for this question.

I have a different doubt though - I am confused about the domain of definition of $f$. Since it is explicitly defined only for three points, wouldn't it be incorrect to evaluate the function for points not in the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>It's eight.

The domain is scaled down by factor $2$: if $x_1$ belong to a domain $D$ of $f$, you need to have $x=x_1/2$ to get $2x = x_1\in D$.

So you have three points forming a triangle with sizes equal half of the original sizes. Its area is then $1/4$ of the original: $32/4 = 8$.</del>

---

**Edit**

I have misunderstood the main part of the problem, as I thought $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are *points in a plane* and they form 'the triangle'. As a result, multiplying those $x$-es (points, i.e *vectors* in $\mathbb R^2$) by $2$ made my imagined triangle twice smaller in all directions, thus reducing its area by $1/4$.
That's also why I've neglected the importance of the other $2$ in my comment.

Now, when I read the problem again, I can see I was completely wrong.

The basic problem is defined as scaling the domain and co-domain of a specific real-valued function of a real-value parameter $f(x)$ by defining a new function $2f(2x)$. In this case multiplying the argument by $2$ shrinks the domain by a coefficient $1/2$, while multiplying the value by $2$ expands the co-domain by a factor $2$. Consequently the area of a figure defined by the function's graph is divided by $2$ and multiplied by $2$, hence stays unchanged.

As for the main question of OP:

> *wouldn't it be incorrect to evaluate the function for points not in the domain.*

the answer is: NO, because we evaluate the function for points *in* the domain.
One needs carefully define, though, what exactly is the function being considered and what exactly is its domain.

To show it more clearly let's describe a new function as a composition:
$$y = 2f(u) \text{  where  } u=2x.\tag{*}$$
Also describe the three domain values with some neutral symbol, like $p$:
 $$f: \{p_1, p_2, p_3\} \to \mathbb R$$
Then we can easily see that for function ($*$) we must obviously have the argument of $f$ belonging to the domain of $f$:
$$u\in D = \{p_1, p_2, p_3\} $$
but that means $x$, the argument of ($*$) must belong to a shrinked domain:
$$x\in \left\{\frac{p_1}2, \frac{p_2}2, \frac{p_3}2\right\} $$

The point is, $f(x)$ and $2f(2x)$ are two *different* functions, hence their domains differ, too; however $f$ itself is evaluated in both cases on the same set of input values.

Comment: This is not answering the question they asked.

Comment: @Greebo Thanks. Now it is.

Comment: Your answer ignores my question - which is more of a meta-question. Also, you have ignored the outer 2 in the 2f(2x) expression.

Comment: @Starlight The outer $2$ has **nothing** to do with a domain, it scales the function output only.

Comment: @CiaPan I agree that it does not change the domain. But it does change the final answer (area of the triangle).

Comment: @Starlight Please see a new answer.

Comment: @Greebo Please see a new answer.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x)$ is defined on $\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$, then $f(2 x)$ is defined on $\{x_1/2,x_2/2,x_3/2\}$

More generally, $f(g(x))$ can only be defined on those points for which $g(x)$ lies in the domain of $f$.

Comment: Thanks. This cleared up my confusion.

Comment: Followup - Can you help with numbers? For example - if f(x) is defined on {3, 6, 7}, then what would be f(2x), and its domain.

Comment: the domain of $f(2x)$ is $\{3/2,6/2,7/2\}$. $3/2$ is OK because $f(2*3/2)=f(3)$, which exists. $6/2$ is OK because $f(2*6/2)=f(6)$, which exists.